# Single Side band Phase noise

Tags: noise, phase

I want to know why the single-side band phase noise is more customary rather than dual-side band phase noise?(even both side band are not the same)

In addition, Could you explain this sentence according to formula for phase noise measurement problems?
[image] 
[image]

Comment: What book is this from?

Comment: Thanks for comment, Phase Noise and Frequency Stability in Oscillators by Enrico Rubiola

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where things get ugly:

Can you *define* what "one-sideband noise power in 1 Hz bandwidth" is?

In my world, it'd just be the PSD of that signal multiplied by 1 Hz. But then, there'd be no need to call it "one-sideband noise power"; it'd just be the noise power density in 1 Hz.

So, "customary" might very much be a "relative" statement. I'd expect that term to only show up in literature that tries to explain signal properties based on a real-valued, analog technological background (maybe trying to bring the complex signal's view to an audience of people that learned the real-valued signal theory first).
 Frankly, I find it an elegant move that much of the modern literature starts right off with complex signals, and just shows that a simple multiplication with a complex sinusoid can move it to baseband, and then introduces the "normal" (as in: non-quadrature) mixer based on that understanding.

This is probably where that "upper and lower sidebands overlap" comes from:

If you take a noisy bandwidth $B$ of passband around a carrier at $f_0$ (you observe $]f_0-\frac B2; f_0 + \frac BS]$), and mix it down using a quadrature mixer (giving you I and Q signals, which we commonly interpret as real and imaginary part of a complex-valued signal), you get signal in $]-\frac B2; \frac B2]$. 
The PSD of noise in that range then is the same as the PSD of noise in the passband. That happens because, mathematically, the quadrature mixer just multiplies with $e^{-j2\pi f_0}$, leading to a "clean" shift of the positive frequencies down to baseband (by $-f_0$).
If you, however, just multiply with a $\cos(2\pi f_0)$, you'll mathematically shift the positive to baseband, but also you shift the negative frequencies, which are a **mirror** of the positive frequencies, up (by $+f_0$).
Now you have the upper sideband being overlaid with the mirror of the lower sideband.
So, looking at this differently, this is an effect of using real-valued signals to represent something that would become complex baseband when mixed with a quadrature mixer.

Note that the statement is obsolete (or plain wrong), because frankly, unless you really want this for some reason, measurement devices either

- mix onto an intermediate frequency (IF), so that none of the signal "crosses" 0 Hz when being downconverted, or
- employ quadrature mixers, where that overlap doesn't happen.

**Update** I'll have to revise my above statement about the obsolence of the statement, because your book,

> Phase Noise and Frequency Stability in Oscillators by Enrico Rubiola

is a book on mixer theory, where you of course analyze the workings of the *elementary* mixers (which can be combined to form e.g. quadrature mixers), so that the author inherently works with the more "physical" real-valued signals, and then he's obviously right:

if you're characterizing the mixing element itself, you can't tell noise above and below the LO apart.